# ng-repeat directive sort the data when using (key, value)

Tags: angularjs

I have a code something like this with ng-repeat = "(key,value) in data". 
In Controller:

```
  $scope.Dates = {"Today":"30",
                  "This Week":"42",
                  "This Month": "Oct",
                  "This Quarter" : "Bad",
                  "This Year" : 2013
                                }
```

and ng-repeat directive as

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in Dates">
{{key}} ==> {{value}}
</div>
```

The output comes in sorted order as

```
This Month ==> Oct
This Quarter ==> Bad
This Week ==> 42 
This Year ==> 2013
Today ==> 30
```

How to get rid of this sorting(strange) as I want keys to be used in code.. I checked google group but there was a fiddle for using two arrays of which one was storing the key values. http://jsfiddle.net/Saulzar/puhML/3/b . Don't want to go with this approach.

Comment: You think alphabetical order is strange?

Comment: No I don't think alphabetical order is strange but don't require here . :D It was meant for the strange behavior !!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is limitation of JavaScript not Angular.

From [ECMAScript Third Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> 4.3.3 An object is a member of the type Object. **It is an unordered collection** of properties each of which contains a primitive
>   value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an
>   object is called a method.

From [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

> The [...] order of enumerating the properties [...] 
>   **is not specified**.

Angular [sorts object keys explicitly](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.1.5/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L225) in order to provide at least some sort of persistent behavior.

**Workaround** is to iterate over extracted keys:

```js
<div ng-repeat="key in keys(Dates)">
  {{key}} ==> {{Dates[key]}}
</div>
```

```js
$scope.keys = function(obj){
  return obj? Object.keys(obj) : [];
}

$scope.Dates = {
  "Today":"30",
  "This Week":"42",
  "This Month": "Oct",
  "This Quarter" : "Bad",
  "This Year" : 2013
};
```

Comment: <div ng-repeat="key in keys(Dates) | orderBy : key">

Comment: It **does not work like this any more**, angular has removed the sorting. See [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31278114/503900).

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: [I've filed a bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210), **feel free to +1**

ECMAScript does not specify order in which keys should be iterated, however all major browsers implement objects as linked hash map (preserves order) and a lot of js libraries depend on this behavior and so we've got used to it and it's hardly going to change.

Angular on the other hand (which is **totally unexpected**) sort it alphabetically. I've inspected the source code myself, it is hard-coded there and it would be nice if it got resolved one day. Otherwise the `(k, v) in obj` feature is **completely useless**.

You really cant do anything with that, **tricking angular** to think your result is an array **is not useful** for anything, because you would need numeric keys then...

If this is okay, you can define getter for length:

```
Object.defineProperty(yourResultObjectOrPrototype, 'length', {
  get: function(){
    return Object.keys(this).length;
  }
})
```

Otherwise **you'll need some kind of filter** which will iterate object using `for(var k in obj)` and store result in array.

Answer (score 7):

There is actually an answer:
it's called orderBy and not sort:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

`{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}`

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'-age'">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Your list just needs to be a list, and you might need an index to know set order

```
$scope.Dates = [{index:1, "Today":"30"},
                  {index:2,"This Week":"42"},
                  {index:3,"This Month": "Oct"},
                  {index:4,"This Quarter" : "Bad"},
                  {index:5,"This Year" : 2013}]
```

and then

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in Dates | orderBy:'index'">
          <td>{{key}}</td>
          <td>{{value}}</td>
         </tr>
```

Comment: MrE : Actually i really didn't wanted any ordering, it should display exactly the same order in which i receive the data, Also second example is an array of objects, so that will just work without index also.

Comment: @icanbeacoder 
The index is there so you can have the order you want, since it is an array as you point out, it will display in the array order. If you wanted a specific order, you'd need the index or you'd need to push the items in the array in the right order to begin with

Answer (score 6):

This is [fixed as of Angular 1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210#issuecomment-114074997).

See details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-6):

> Previously, the order of items when using ngRepeat to iterate over object properties was guaranteed to be consistent by sorting the keys into alphabetic order.
>
> Now, the order of the items is browser dependent based on the order returned from iterating over the object using the `for key in obj` syntax.
>
> It seems that browsers generally follow the strategy of providing keys in the order in which they were defined...

Comment: This is **broken**, as there’s no way to get ng-repeat to sort any more while retaining the key ☹

Answer (score 2):

I was able to sort an Object of Strings by Key alphabetically like this with ng-repeat!

In my controller:

```
$scope.build_config = {
  build_path :  "/x/eng/build",
  arch : "x86",
  variant : "debug",
  run_method : "boot", 
};

$scope.get_keys = function (obj) {
  if (obj)
    return Object.keys(obj);
};
```

In my HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="key in get_keys(build_config) | orderBy:'toString()'">
      <td> {{key}} </td>
      <td> {{selected.build_config[key]}} </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys doesn't reserve the order - FYI
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

// array like object with random key ordering

```
var an_obj = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.keys(an_obj)); // console: ['2', '7', '100']
```

I convert it into an array of object

```
$scope.Dates = [
        { id: "Today",      value:"30" },
        { id: "This Week",  value:"42" },
        { id: "This Month", value: "Oct" },
        { id: "This Quarter", value : "Bad" },
        { id: "This Year",  value : 2013 }
    ];

<li ng-repeat="date in Dates">{{date.id}} -> {{date.value}}</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hqew68k/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, as explained in Angular's documentation for ngRepeat

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties

when using it to iterate over the properties of an object, it will not work

> The built-in filters orderBy and filter do not work with objects, and
>   will throw an error if used with one.

The best solution in this case I think that is using arrays instead of an object and its properties. Therefore, just convert it to an array, iterating the properties of your object and pushing to the new array for example. After all, I think that would be the natural choice to a collection, instead of a single object with many properties.