# How can I sort a directive output?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following Directive:

```
app.directive('sidebar', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<li ng-repeat="(keymenu, valmenu) in menu"><a href="{{valmenu.url}}"><i class="{{valmenu.image}}"></i><span class="hidden-sm">{{keymenu}}</span></a></li>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.menu = {
        "Home": {
          "sort": 1,
          "url": "/",
          "image": "fa fa-bar-chart-o"
        },
        "Datasources": {
          "sort": 2,
          "url": "/datasources",
          "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
        },
        "Logger": {
          "sort": 3,
          "url": "/Logger",
          "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
        }

      }
    }
  }
});
```

Currently the order is: `Datasources, Home, Logger` I would like to order it either by the `sort` property or by it's 'natural' order as the elements are ordered within the `scope.menu` object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-repeat directive sort the data when using (key, value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676694/ng-repeat-directive-sort-the-data-when-using-key-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `orderBy` direcly into the `<li />` template:

This code will sort your menu for the property name that you want:

```
'<li ng-repeat="(keymenu, valmenu) in menu| orderBy:myProperty">'
```

EDIT:

You should change the way your JSON looks, or you will have issues to access and order the menu. The way you did every menu entry is a different object, you should do like this:

```
scope.menu =[
   {
      "name": "Home",
      "sort": 1,
      "url": "/",
      "image": "fa fa-bar-chart-o"
    },
    {
      "name":"Datasources",
      "sort": 2,
      "url": "/datasources",
      "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
    },
    {
      "name": "Logger",
      "sort": 3,
      "url": "/Logger",
      "image": "fa fa-dashboard"
    }
  ]
```

Then sort by `name` for exemple:

```
'<li ng-repeat="(keymenu, valmenu) in menu| orderBy:name">'
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.. I tried ``.. | orderBy:sort`` and ``.. | orderBy:valmenu.sort``

Comment: The issue is your JSON, you should put the menu name inside, tha way you construct it you have to access like this "Home".sort.