# Remove Automatic ordering from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json object. It is not ordered in ascending order.

```
 $scope.myData = {
        "MAX" : "some value",
        "Forms" : "some value",
        "Grids And Tables" : "some value",
        "Navigation" : "some value",
        "Services & APIs" : "some value"
  }
```

I used ng-repeat for showing it in my html template. I got the result but, the order has changed in to ascending order.

```
Forms
Grids And Tables
MAX
Navigation
Services & APIs
```

How to prevent angular js from automatic ordering?

Check this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4MaCiukH3EjYy8UGt22M?p=preview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-repeat directive sort the data when using (key, value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676694/ng-repeat-directive-sort-the-data-when-using-key-value)

Answer (score 9):

As suggested, it's not possible to sort object keys. Buy you can sort over an array created using those object keys -

```
$scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.myData);
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="key in keys">
    {{key}} - 
    {{myData[key]}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is what I meant in my answer with you can iterate over a separate array and index into it. I didn't think of using Object.keys though. That's a pretty good idea.

Comment: Yup, kind of stupid of me to have added a new answer. Should have just edited your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The order of iterating over object keys in javascript is technically undefined. While most browsers will iterate over the object in the defined order, you should not rely on this behavior.

In the case of angular, `ng-repeat` needs to always sort the keys so that order is deterministic even when keys are added after the fact. It is not possible to change this behavior because it would break the directive as keys are added or removed dynamically.

If you need to rely on the ordering of your data, then an object hash is not the correct data structure. You should either re-format your data as an array, or simply create a separate array with the order of the keys and do your ng-repeat over it. Using the keys to index into the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your keys manually like 1,2,3,4,5 and then on front end slice them with string.slice(1). Hope it helps.