# Angular ngRepeat orderBy order in Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following JSON data and I'd like for Angular to do an `ngRepeat` for each `key` inside `Specification` and be displayed in the same order as they are in the object:

```
"Specification": {
    "Screen": "15.4\" Retina display",
    "Resolution": "2880 x 1800",
    "HDD": "512GB SSD",
    "RAM": "16GB RAM",
    "CPU": "Intel Core i7 2.30 Ghz Processor",
    "Software": "Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks"
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectedProduct.Specification">
        <span ng-class="{{key | lowercase}}">{{value}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The above code outputs the data in a random order, not the order of appearance in the array.

Comment: Okkkkkkkk but what's the issue? Does that code not work? Unexpected output?

Comment: This will be relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676694/ng-repeat-directive-sort-the-data-when-using-key-value

Comment: @SterlingArcher Pressed submit too early, the above code outputs the keys in a random order.

Comment: Angular team has decided not to support orderBy when using an object in ng-repeat. See [the discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286), and there are some workarounds in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers (e.g. Chrome) will re-arrange the keys alphabetically, so there is no reliable, cross-browser way to retain the key order for an object. You should either turn it into an array, or specify the key order separately (e.g. as a separate array).

---

**UPDATE**

As runTurm correctly pointed out, in `ngRepeat` specifically the keys are ordered alphabetically by Angular. So, the easiest way to retain a specific order would be to use a separate array for holding the keys in desired order:

```
/* CONTROLLER: */
$scope.keys = ["Screen", "Resolution", "HDD", "RAM", "CPU", "Software"];
$scope.selectedProduct = {
    Specification: {
        ...
    },
    ...
};

<!-- VIEW: -->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="key in keys">
        <span class="{{key | lowercase}}">{{selectedProduct.Specification[key]}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you find it more readable or if you plan to use `selectedProduct.Specification[key]` in multiple places, you could use `ngInit` to alias it as `value`:

```
    <li ng-repeat="key in keys" ng-init="value=selectedProduct.Specification[key]">
        <span class="{{key | lowercase}}">{{value}}</span>
    </li>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/m2rpt7ty/)**.

Comment: Can you provide a reference? try using `for-in` in chrome, it doesn't re-arrange the keys alphabetically.

Comment: The keys are sorted by intention in the `ng-repeat` code, see [ngRepeat.js#L289](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.22/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L289). And there is a discussion [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter that will return an array object representation of your key-value object via `angular.forEach()`.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gJ8IwQdrMd86i1jtDZ0T?p=preview)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    var specs = {
      "Screen": "15.4\" Retina display",
      "Resolution": "2880 x 1800",
      "HDD": "512GB SSD",
      "RAM": "16GB RAM",
      "CPU": "Intel Core i7 2.30 Ghz Processor",
      "Software": "Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks"
    };

    $scope.specs = $filter('keyValue')(specs);
  })

  .filter('keyValue', function() {
    return function(object) {
      var array = [];

      angular.forEach(object, function(value, index) {
        array.push({
          value: value,
          key: index
        });
      });

      return array;
    };
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in specs">
    <span ng-class="{{item.key | lowercase}}">{{item.value}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly in ANgular but can either modify your object being bound to the view or can create a custom filter for same. I have used the Object.keys() method to return keys and then use the same for computed object.

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', function($scope){
    var data = {"Specification": {
    "Screen": "15.4\" Retina display",
    "Resolution": "2880 x 1800",
    "HDD": "512GB SSD",
    "RAM": "16GB RAM",
    "CPU": "Intel Core i7 2.30 Ghz Processor",
    "Software": "Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks"
    }};

    var filter = Object.keys(data.Specification), 
        b = [];
    angular.forEach(filter, function(key, value){
       b.push(data.Specification[key]);
    });

    $scope.selectedProducts = b;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0guqq9a4/1)**