# Retrieving the keys in the insertion order with ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON string that is assigned to angular model and is used to loop through and display the key and value on the UI .

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in Profile>
    <td>{{key}} :</td>
    <td>{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

This works except that the order of the keys is not same as the model or 
My model looks like below

```
"Profile": {
    "UserID": 1234,
    "User Name": "SomeName",
    "Email Address": "someone@yahoo.com",
    "Age": 29,
    "Occupation": ""
  }
```

The out put is and I would like to get it in the same order as the JSON string , how can i achieve it?

```
Age :29
Email Address : someone@yahoo.com
Occupation :
UserID : 1234
User Name : SomeName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your really need a workaround for this as objects are unordered, as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676694/ng-repeat-directive-sort-the-data-when-using-key-value):

Here is the workaround expressed for your example:

Or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michiganfootball20/sqgbdftb/):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="key in keys(Profile)">
            <td>{{key}}: {{Profile[key]}}</tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.keys = function(obj){return obj? Object.keys(obj) : [];}
    $scope.Profile = {
         "UserID": 1234,
         "User Name": "SomeName",
         "Email Address": "someone@yahoo.com",
         "Age": 29,
         "Occupation": ""
    };
});
```